# Why does Maximize return this unevaluated?

Tags: distributions, maximum, maximize

```
Maximize[{PDF[NormalDistribution[0, sigma], x], sigma > 0}, x, Reals]
```

Just returns unevaluated (when, obviously, it should return `0` along with the function value there).

Any ideas?

**Edit**: This seems to be a general trend over many PDFs:

```
Maximize[{PDF[GammaDistribution[a, b], x], a > 0 && b > 0 && x > 0}, x]
```

returns unevaluated, as does:

```
Maximize[{PDF[LogNormalDistribution[mu, sigma], x], mu > 0 && sigma > 0 && x > 0}, x]
```

and:

```
Maximize[{PDF[StudentTDistribution[nu], x], nu > 0 && x > 0}, x]
```

and so on... I should have specified but I'm not interested in finding the modes of a specific case (like the normal), but more interested in why Mathematica can't handle these.

Comment: As the output of `Maximize[{(-(x^2/(2* sigma^2))), sigma > 0}, x]` shows, the assumption is not taken into account.

Comment: I'd like to add that `Maximize` has problems with transcendental functions.

Answer (score 4):

```
A workaround
    
    $Version
    
    (* "13.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)" *)
    
    Clear["Global`*"]
    
    f[x_] = PDF[NormalDistribution[0, sigma], x];
    
    {max, arg} = Assuming[sigma > 0,
      {f[x] /. #, #} &[
       Solve[
         {D[#, x] == 0, D[#, {x, 2}] < 0} &[f[x]], x][[1]]]]
    
    (* {1/(Sqrt[2 π] sigma), {x -> 0}} *)
```

**EDIT:** More generally,

```
f2[x_] = PDF[NormalDistribution[m, sigma], x];

{max, arg} =
 Assuming[sigma > 0 && m ∈ Reals,
  {f2[x] /. #, Reverse /@ #} &[{Simplify@Reduce[
        {D[#, x] == 0, D[#, {x, 2}] < 0} &[f2[x]], x] // 
  ToRules}[[1]]]]

(* {1/(Sqrt[2 π] sigma), {x -> m}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks @Bob. This is sort of beautiful in how hideously complex it is to accomplish a simple task!

Answer (score 3):

For some distributions taking the log of the density results in an answer:

```
FullSimplify[
 Maximize[{LogLikelihood[NormalDistribution[μ, sigma], {x}]}, x, Reals], 
 Assumptions -> sigma > 0]
(* {-(1/2) Log[2 π] - Log[sigma], {x -> μ}} *)
```

For others, more manipulations prior to using `Maximize` are necessary.  Also, all 3 of your examples work if specific values are given for the parameters:

```
Maximize[{PDF[GammaDistribution[3, 6], x], x > 0}, x]
(* {1/(3 E^2), {x -> 12}} *)

Maximize[{PDF[LogNormalDistribution[1, 2], x], x > 0}, x]
(* {E/(2 Sqrt[2 π]), {x -> 1/E^3}} *)

Maximize[PDF[StudentTDistribution[13], x], x]
(* {1024/(231 Sqrt[13] π), {x -> 0}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks @JimB. Any idea just why Mathematica struggles with the PDFs as they stand?

Comment: I wouldn't use the word "struggles".  *Mathematica* certainly decides in those situations that it can't find an answer.  (Certainly that's better than producing a wrong answer.)  And things are more complicated than restricting solutions to reals or positive reals.  For example, the mode (which is what you're after) is not always finite.  For a gamma distribution, the mode occurs at 0 for $0<a<1$ and $(a-1)b$ for $a\geq 1$.  Talking to *Mathematica* support might help.